# Using foreach loop in r returning NA

Tags: r, foreach, na, doparallel

I would like to use the "foreach" loop in R (package foreach + doParallel) but in my work i found that the loop returns some NA and the classic "for" loop returns the value I want :

```
    library(foreach)
    library(doParallel)

    ncore=as.numeric(Sys.getenv('NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS'))-1
    registerDoParallel(cores=ncore)

    B=2

    a = vector()
    b = vector()

    foreach(i = 1:B, .packages = "ez",.multicombine = T,.inorder = T, .combine = 'c')%dopar%{
      a[i] = i + 1
      return(a)
    }

    for(i in 1:B){
      b[i] = i + 1
      b
      }
```

As you can see if you try it, the object "a" returns a vector with 2, NA and 3 while the object "b" returns 2 and 3 (that's what I want).

I actually can't understand why there's a "NA" in my results...

Comment: The retrun of the foreach loop is for `i = 1, a = c(2)` but for `i = 2`it is `a = c(NA, 3)`because the vector is initialized before the loop and empty for each single loop. Within the for-loop, the second time it is called it is not empty anymore. Therefore in `.combine`it is added to c(2, NA, 3).

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! Helped me to understand how it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `foreach` does not change the global object `a`. Try to combine with `list`. It will be easier to understand what is happening. I have increased `B` to `3`.

```
> B=3
> 
> a = vector()
> 
> foreach(i = 1:B, .multicombine = T, .inorder = T, .combine = 'list') %dopar% {
+   a[i] = i + 1
+   return(a)
+ }
[[1]]
[1] 2

[[2]]
[1] NA  3

[[3]]
[1] NA NA  4
```

We can see that in each iteration an empty vector `a` is taken and one value of it is filled. If you `c` combine the result you get `NA` values.

```
> foreach(i = 1:B, .multicombine = T, .inorder = T, .combine = 'c') %dopar% {
+   a[i] = i + 1
+   return(a)
+ }
[1]  2 NA  3 NA NA  4
```

In this example you could do.

```
> a <- foreach(i = 1:B, .multicombine = T, .inorder = T, .combine = 'c') %dopar% {
+   i + 1
+ }
> a
[1] 2 3 4
```

Comment: Thanks you very much!
Now I understand better how the "foreach" loop works and I will use it in my more complicated work (this one was just to try to understand what was happening).

Answer (score 0):

`foreach` works more like `lapply` than a for-loop.

You can simply do `foreach(i = 1:B, .combine = 'c') %dopar% { i + 1 }`
(`.multicombine` and `.inorder` are already `TRUE` but you may want to set `.maxcombine` to a high value).