# running foreach iteratively with dopar

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I am trying to translate a "for" loop into a "foreach" loop in order to be able to run that function in parallel with dopar. However values in the loop are not stored so I get NAs.

I initialize a matrix and give it a value for its first column as follows:

```r
N<-2 
m<-2 
t<-5 
probas_no_choice<-matrix(0.9,N*m,t)

probas_no_choice2<-matrix(NA,N*m,t)
probas_no_choice2[,1]=probas_no_choice[,1]
```

Then I replaced

```r
for (i in 2:t) {probas_no_choice2[,i]=probas_no_choice[,i]*probas_no_choice2[,i-1]}
```

with

```r
foreach (i = 2:t) %do% {probas_no_choice2[,i]=probas_no_choice[,i]*probas_no_choice2[,i-1]}
```

and this works but is slower than for.

Then I tried

```r
foreach (i = 2:t, .combine=c) %dopar% {probas_no_choice2[,i]=probas_no_choice[,i]*probas_no_choice2[,i-1]}
```

and this outputs NAs for all i>2.

I would like to know how I can run the later code so it outputs the same result as in the for loop.

This question differs from a previous one that has been marked as "duplicate" because I progressively build the matrix by using values generated in the loop, i.e. `A2[,i]<-A1[,i]*A2[,i-1]` rather than simply `A2[,i]<-i+1`.

Comment: add a `return(probas_no_choice2[,i])`. When running on a cluster variables are used differently and are not inside your r environment. You have to call them with a return call, otherwise your memory would be flooded with useless variables.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by `does not work beyond i=2`. Does it process but you don't get the right result? Does it terminate with an error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using foreach loop in r returning NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45919852/using-foreach-loop-in-r-returning-na)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, see added text about how the questions differ.